# Date picker control does not capture data

Tags: infopath, datepicker

The date picker control worked perfectly when my site was on SharePoint 2013 once the SharePoint site collection was upgraded to SP2016 the date picker controls for all my InfoPath forms became disabled, icon is greyed out and won't capture any data.

If I preview the form prior to publishing it, the date control icons collapse and are able to capture the date as I save to the list. While troubleshooting the date control I came across the `DateTime1033` is undefined error which led me to promote my site to a top-level site, but this found no success.

I've created a new list with InfoPath form with date picker controls to see if my new list with date pickers would work, but those controls aren't working either. Would appreciate some assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: I navigated to the FormResource.aspx page and received the following - 'LoadedScriptFiles.boolServerError = true;' can someone assist with this issue?